# When will S99 launch if it isn't in a normal form?

Tags: init, sles

If I do a:

```
echo "foobar" > /etc/init.d/foobar
chmod 744 /etc/init.d/foobar
ln -s /etc/init.d/foobar /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S99foobar
```

on a SLES 11, then when will the "foobar" command launch during boot? as the last S99? or a normal start script format would be needed for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SysVinit start/stop scripts are launched in alphanumerical order according to the sorting order of the default "C" (aka POSIX) locale, so `S99foobar` will start after any `S99[a-e]*` scripts but before any `S99[g-z]*` scripts.

The scripts are launched by `/etc/init.d/rc` master script. The relevant code is essentially:

```
for link in /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S[0-9][0-9]*; do
    test -x "$link" || continue

    # omitted optimization: if previous runlevel already started this service, don't start it again
    # omitted logic: if $DO_CONFIRM is set, prompt for each service
    # omitted logging

    $link start; status=$?

    # omitted status reporting/logging logic based on value of $status
done
```